# socket.emit doesn't get data to front side

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have an app using socket.io to communicate between server side and front side, sometimes the socket.emit in the server side doesn't transfer the data to the front even though the data exists and I get a timeout error in the listenResponse in the front side.
This happens in a random way, my code is very basic, from server side :

```
return socket.emit(rep, {
                                        rep : response,
                                        name: response.name
                                    }
                                );
```

I checked with a console.log in the server side that response is not empty.
Could you please help me fix this to make sure that data is transfered to the front side ? 
Thank you

Comment: To help you, we need have some information, show the some code, show logs from front & backend. Without this, it's impossible to figure out what's the case.

Comment: in the front side there is a setTimeout function that renders the error that it didn't get the response , while in the server side response contains data

Comment: Do you receive these errors in usual flow or debug mode?

Comment: in usual flow, I just put a "console.log" to see what's going on